# How do I write to a .csv file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am writing a simple script with Python3.6 and am using the csv module to create a csv file.  My code is attached below, and is a carbon copy of multiple examples I have found online, but when I run the code, I get the error message `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not a 'str'`.

```
import csv
File_Name = Test.csv
with open(File_Name, 'wb') as csvfile:
   filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
   filewriter = writerow(['Paul','Mary'])
```

Comment: Use `with open(File_Name, 'w') as csvfile`

Comment: where does `writerow` come from? You are overriding `filewriter`

Comment: In Python 3.x the proper way to open the csv file for writing is `open(open(File_Name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:` as shown in the examples in the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). You also need to use `filewriter.writerow(['Paul','Mary'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the binary mode, you can use this :

```
with open(File_Name, 'w') as csvfile:
   filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
   filewriter.writerow(['Paul','Mary'])
```

Check the table [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) to see details about the different modes available.

Answer (score 3):

The `csvwriter` instance shouldn't be reassigned to. It should be used to write the rows.

In python 3, you should open the file in write only mode with `newline=''` per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

```
import csv

filename = 'Test.csv'

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
   file_writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
   file_writer.writerow(['Paul','Mary'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change from 'wb' to 'w' and file name should be in quotation("Test.csv" or 'Test.csv') see below

```
import csv
File_Name = "Test.csv"
with open(File_Name, 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    filewriter.writerow(['Paul','Mary'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you are opened file in a binary mode

```
with open(File_Name, 'wb') as csvfile:
```

This means that all data read from the file is returned as bytes objects, not str.
If you don't need it, try:

```
with open(File_Name, 'w') as csvfile:
```

Also you should use `writerow` method of the `csvwriter` instead of reassign it:

```
file_writer.writerow(['Paul','Mary'])
```